# I can not find my wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless

When I open my laptop, I only can connect with wired network. what can I do to connect with the wireless network?

[image: output of additional drivers]

[image: output of lscpi]
[output lshw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7lgr.png)

Comment: Please provide with more information regarding the hardware, your wireless card model may help.

Comment: i just added some screenshot

Comment: @Emmet i just added some screenshot

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: can you please post the out put of this command lshw -class network

Comment: @kc1di i just added

Comment: What does the output of rfkill list show?

Comment: @kc1di      0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no